# Python ctype can't find dll?

Tags: python, dll, ctypes

Python ctype can't find AntTweakBar.dll ?? and the file dosn't exist for python OS file system call, but exists in the c:\Windows\System32 dir.

```
C:\Users\dkm>dir c:\Windows\System32\ant*dll
 Volume in drive C is Windows 7
 Volume Serial Number is FC61-5FBB

 Directory of c:\Windows\System32

23/07/2012  12:05 AM           641,536 AntTweakBar.dll
22/07/2012  11:43 PM           774,144 AntTweakBar64.dll
               2 File(s)      1,415,680 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  47,418,232,832 bytes free

C:\Users\dkm>python
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes.util import find_library
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.exists('C:\\Windows\\System32\\antweakbar.dll')
False
>>> find_library("AntTweakBar")
>>>
```

why can't ctype find the dll?

Comment: With the 'tT' - still show up as false
>>> import os
>>> print os.path.exists('C:\\Windows\\System32\\AntTweakBar.dll')
False

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 t's in the file name

`antweakbar.dll` - name given by you

`AntTweakBar.dll` - actual file name

`C:\\Windows\\System32\\antweakbar.dll`
should be `C:\\Windows\\System32\\anttweakbar.dll`

for example (checking with inetcfg.dll, as i don't have anttweakbar.dll), see below for Python 2.7.2

```
In [136]: import os

In [137]: os.path.exists("C:\\Windows\\System32\\inetcfg.dll")
Out[137]: True
```

Comment: FYI: anttweakbar is a opegl UI (http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools:anttweakbar) and the python binding is (http://www.loria.fr/~rougier/coding/python.html)